Lifting a point to the dual line bundle
I am reading some notes regarding GIT and symplectic geometry.

What  does it mean in this context to lift $x$ to $\tilde{x}\in \mathcal{O}_x(-1)$ ?

Recall that $\mathbb{CP}^n=(\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\})/\mathbb{C}^\times$. More intuitively, points in $\mathbb{CP}^n$ correspond to complex lines in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$. Then by definition $\mathcal{O}(-1)=\{(l,z)\in \mathbb{CP}^n\times\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\mid z\in l\}$. And now is it clear what is meant by lifting $x$ to $\tilde{x}\in\mathcal{O}(-1)$, it means that we choose $\tilde{x}$ to be an arbitrary point in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ which lies on the line defined by $x\in\mathbb{CP}^n$.
More generally, I would think of $X\subseteq\mathbb{CP}^n$, and $\mathcal{O}_X(-1)=\mathcal{O}(-1)|_X$ for intuition.
However, strictly speaking, the statement doesn't invoke any of this. It simply says that you have a complex line bundle $\pi:L\to X$, and for $x\in X$ you let $\tilde{x}\in \pi^{-1}(x)$ be arbitrary.

Honestly, thank you for taking the time to explain it to me. I often get paralyzed with the feeling of confusion and not knowing with certainty if the way I understand it is correct.
